# Como alterar as cores do menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Quando criamos um menu com Bootstrap, ele por *default*, cria uma faixa preta em toda área do menu. Fica bonito assim. Porem, na empresa em que eu estou, a cor predominante é o magenta, logo pediram para eu alterar essa cor de preta para magenta.

Como posso alterar isso?

Comment: qual a razão do downvote? O que errei dessa vez?

Comment: Inspecciona o elemento a partir do teu browser e vê qual a classe onde podes alterar a cor

Comment: o downvote talvez seja pela pergunta "não apresentar nenhum esforço na pesquisa", digo eu

Comment: Cara, é necessário colocar um link aqui, ou talvez o HTML em questão. Como vamos saber exatamente do que se trata?
De qualquer forma, pesquise por `navbar`.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: Que tipo de menu estás a falar?

Comment: 10 segundos no google - "change bootstrap colors" e o primeiro link é: http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/

Comment: Miguel, pelo inspetor do navegador eu acho o cara, mas não consigo localizar ele no meu projeto para fazer a alteração, entende. Lá no navegador eu tenho: bootstrap.less:4013.Só que não acho esse cara lá. Pelo navegador eu edito, mas preciso fazer isso no projeto agora.

Comment: Porque depois no teu projecto tens de ir ao ficheiro css alterar as propriedades. Deve estar em Content > bootstrap. Tens de alterar no ficheiro bootstrap.css e no bootstrap.min.css. Ou então na div do menu metes logo `style=" defines o estilo aqui"`

Comment: Consegui char. É que no browser a cor esta assim: #22222 e no código estava assim:@navbar-inverse-bg. Por isso eu apanhei, mas já resolvi.

Comment: Como as pessoas sabe que não houve esforço? Acho isso muito maldoso. Conforme comentei estava apanhando, devido eu ver uma coisa e no código outra. Tudo bem, vou remover a pergunta.

Comment: [*`"Compartilhar sua pesquisa ajuda a todos. Diga-nos o que foi que você encontrou e por que não satisfez às suas necessidades. Isto demonstra que você usou seu tempo para tentar ajudar a si mesmo e nos poupa de reiterar respostas óbvias e, principalmente, ajuda você a obter uma resposta mais específica e relevante!"`*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Na verdade eu acho a pergunta muito boa e relevante, não percebo os votos negativos.

Answer (score 16):

Você pode alterar as classes do CSS ou utilizar ferramentas como [**Lavish**](http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/) ou [**TWBSColor**](http://twbscolor.smarchal.com/).

E encontrei [a seguinte pergunta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529274/change-navbar-color-in-twitter-bootstrap-3) que é muito completa e didática. Transcrevo e traduzo aqui a resposta do usuário [zessx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238019/zessx):

> ### NavBars disponíveis
>
> Existem 2 tipos de navbar :
>
> ```html
> <!-- A clara -->
> <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"></nav>
> <!-- A escura -->
> <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation"></nav>
> ```
>
> ### Utilizando as cores padrões
>
> Estas são as cores padrões e para que servem :
>
> - `#F8F8F8` : navbar background
> - `#E7E7E7` : navbar border
> - `#777` : default color
> - `#333` : hover color (`#5E5E5E` for `.nav-brand`)
> - `#555` : active color
> - `#D5D5D5` : active background
>
> ### Estilo Padrão
>
> Se quiser mudar algo no estilo, este é o CSS que precisas alterar :
>
> ```css
> /* navbar */
> .navbar-default {
>     background-color: #F8F8F8;
>     border-color: #E7E7E7;
> }
> /* title */
> .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
>     color: #777;
> }
> .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
> .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
>     color: #5E5E5E;
> }
> /* link */
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
>     color: #777;
> }
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
>     color: #333;
> }
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
>     color: #555;
>     background-color: #E7E7E7;
> }
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
>     color: #555;
>     background-color: #D5D5D5;
> }
> /* caret */
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a .caret {
>     border-top-color: #777;
>     border-bottom-color: #777;
> }
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:hover .caret,
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .dropdown > a:focus .caret {
>     border-top-color: #333;
>     border-bottom-color: #333;
> }
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a .caret, 
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover .caret, 
> .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus .caret {
>     border-top-color: #555;
>     border-bottom-color: #555;
> }
> /* mobile version */
> .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
>     border-color: #DDD;
> }
> .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
> .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
>     background-color: #DDD;
> }
> .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
>   background-color: #CCC;
> }
> @media (max-width: 767px) {
>   .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
>       color: #777;
>     }
>   .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
>   .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
>           color: #333;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> ### Exemplos de navbar com cores customizadas
>
> Aqui estão 4 examplos de navbars com cores diferentes:
>   **[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zessx/drSbw/)**
>
> [image]
>
> E o código SCSS :
>
> ```css
> $bgDefault        : #e74c3c;
> $bgHighlight  : #c0392b;
> $colDefault   : #ecf0f1;
> $colHover         : #ffbbbc;
> .navbar-default {
>   background-color: $bgDefault;
>   border-color: $bgHighlight;
>   .navbar-brand {
>     color: $colDefault;
>     &:hover, &:focus { 
>       color: $colHighlight; }}
>   .navbar-text {
>     color: $colDefault; }
>   .navbar-nav {
>     > li {
>       > a {
>         color: $colDefault;
>         &:hover,  &:focus {
>           color: $colHighlight; }}}
>     > .active {
>       > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
>         color: $colHighlight;
>         background-color: $bgHighlight; }}
>     > .open {
>       > a, > a:hover, > a:focus {
>         color: $colHighlight;
>         background-color: $bgHighlight; }}}
>   .navbar-toggle {
>     border-color: $bgHighlight;
>     &:hover, &:focus {
>       background-color: $bgHighlight; }
>     .icon-bar {
>       background-color: $colDefault; }}
>   .navbar-collapse,
>   .navbar-form {
>     border-color: $colDefault; }
>   .navbar-link {
>     color: $colDefault;
>     &:hover {
>       color: $colHighlight; }}}
> @media (max-width: 767px) {
>   .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
>     > li > a {
>       color: $colDefault;
>       &:hover, &:focus {
>         color: $colHighlight; }}
>     > .active {
>       > a, > a:hover, > a:focus, {
>         color: $colHighlight;
>         background-color: $bgHighlight; }}}
> }
> ```
>
> ### E finalmente, um pequeno presente
>
> Eu criei um pequeno script que te permite gerar o seu tema :
>   **[TWBSColor - Generate your own Bootstrap navbar](http://smarchal.com/twbscolor/?bd=e74c3c&bh=c0392b&cd=ecf0f1&ch=ffbbbc)**
>
> *[Atualização] : TWBSColor agora gera código SCSS/SASS/LESS/CSS.*