# Como mudar a cor do botão da navbar bootstrap?

Tags: css

[image]

Eu consegui deixar a barra azul mas o botão sempre fica verde independente da cor

Estou usando esse codigo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Site-base</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="css/estilo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="principal" >
 <header><img src="IMG/intelcore.jpg" alt="some text"  width=310 height=200></header>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Computadores <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Celulares <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tablets <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Buscar" style="background-color:white;">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </nav>
   
 <aside>
  <div class="list-group">
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" style="height: 67px">
    Equipamentos:
   </a>
   <a href="file:///C:/Users/Cleit/OneDrive/%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho/Site/monitores.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Placa de vídeo</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Processadores</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Monitores</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Fonte</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Gabinete</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Mouses</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Teclados</a>
  </div>
 </aside>
   
 <section>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
     <img src="IMG/rtx.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="RTX" height=500px>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="IMG/gtx300.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="GTX300" height=500px>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="IMG/intelcore.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." height=500px>
    </div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div>
 </section>
 
 <main>
  <div class="container" style="min-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
   <div class="item item1">
    <div class="card" style="width: 19rem;">
     <img src="IMG/rtxazul.jpg" class="card-img-top" style="hidth=10px;">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text"></p>
     </div>
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">COMPRAR</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">DETALHES</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
       <div class="item item2">
    <div class="card" style="width: 19rem;">
     <img src="IMG/teclado.jif" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text"></p>
     </div>
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
       <div class="item item3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 19rem;">
     <img src="IMG/rtx.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text"></p>
     </div>
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">COMPRAR</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">DETALHES</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item item4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 19rem;">
     <img src="IMG/rtx.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text"></p>
     </div>
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </main>
 
 <footer>

 </footer>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Vi em alguns sites que se usar o seguinte codigo mudaria a cor, porem muda o estilo da barra também e o botão some:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
```

Answer (score 2):

A cor do botão você deve alterar na classe da tag `<button>`... Por exemplo:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
```

Seria interessante se você colocasse todo o código do HTML para que a gente pudesse ajudar melhor.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Site-base</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="css/estilo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="principal" >
 <header><img src="IMG/intelcore.jpg" alt="some text"  width=310 height=200></header>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Computadores <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Celulares <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tablets <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Buscar" style="background-color:white;">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
<!-- a classe da tag acima foi alterado de success para secondary -->
   </form>
  </div>
 </nav>
   
 <aside>
  <div class="list-group">
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" style="height: 67px">
    Equipamentos:
   </a>
   <a href="file:///C:/Users/Cleit/OneDrive/%C3%81rea%20de%20Trabalho/Site/monitores.html" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Placa de vídeo</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Processadores</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Monitores</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Fonte</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Gabinete</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Mouses</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" style="height: 63px">Teclados</a>
  </div>
 </aside>
   
 <section>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
     <img src="IMG/rtx.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="RTX" height=500px>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="IMG/gtx300.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="GTX300" height=500px>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="IMG/intelcore.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." height=500px>
    </div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
  </div>
 </section>
 
 <main>
  <div class="container" style="min-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
   <div class="item item1">
    <div class="card" style="width: 19rem;">
     <img src="IMG/rtxazul.jpg" class="card-img-top" style="hidth=10px;">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text"></p>
     </div>
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">COMPRAR</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">DETALHES</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
       <div class="item item2">
    <div class="card" style="width: 19rem;">
     <img src="IMG/teclado.jif" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text"></p>
     </div>
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
       <div class="item item3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 19rem;">
     <img src="IMG/rtx.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text"></p>
     </div>
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#" class="card-link">COMPRAR</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">DETALHES</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item item4">
    <div class="card" style="width: 19rem;">
     <img src="IMG/rtx.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
      <p class="card-text"></p>
     </div>
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
      <li class="list-group-item"></li>
     </ul>
     <div class="card-body">
      <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link"></a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </main>
 
 <footer>

 </footer>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Coloquei o codigo todo, ta meio bugado mas acho que da para entender

Comment: Fiz a alteração no seu código. Veja se irá atender.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score 2):

Cara as cores estão discritas na documentação oficial, basta vc consultar no link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#outline-buttons

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Dark</button>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Primary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Secondary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Success</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Danger</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Warning</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info">Info</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light">Light</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Dark</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exempo:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>
```

Conforme este [link](https://www.portalgsti.com.br/2017/08/como-mudar-a-cor-do-navbar-com-bootstrap-4.html). Espero que te ajude.

Encontrei essa resposta no stackoverflow que acho que também pode te ajudar. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/29734/72989

Answer (score -1):

**LINK PARA A DOCUMENTAÇÃO DO NAVBAR**
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

**CODIGO**

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li.active a{ 
    background-color: #6dafad;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius:
    margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  background-color: #6dafad;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  background-color: #6dafad;
}
```